# want to use databind <%=minqty %> with INPUT html control in c#.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I want to use the following statement in our c#.net aspx pages.

```
<input type="number" min="<%=minvalue %>" max="<%=maxvalue %>" step="<%=stepvalue %>" id="test" runat="server" />
```

instead of

```
<input type="number" min="100" max="1000" step="50" id="test" runat="server" />
```

the value of minvalue, maxvalue and stepvalue is coming from a database.

```
int minvalue = 10;
int maxvalue = 1000;
int stepvalue = 50;
```

please help us. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problem in your implementation then create an user control and then set properties from server side which you can easily access on your client side code.  a property on your user control with the datatype of the data you want to pass to it, and populate it in your page on creation of the control.

```
public class myControl : Control
{
  public int maxValue {get; set;}
  public int minValue {get; set;}
  public int stepValue {get; set;}
  .................

}
```

In the code behind:

```
myControl ctrl = new myControl();
ctrl.maxValue = 1000;
ctrl.minValue = 10;
ctrl.stepValue = 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<%#` as that is a binding expression.

```
<input type="number" min="<%# minvalue %>" id="test" runat="server" />
```

But you have to call `DataBind()` in code behind for it to work.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Note that the variables must be `public`.