# Inline Expression <%= %> in html attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I'm working on trying to implement a simple cache work-around for a project.

In the project I have a public string:

```
public string noCache = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
```

I'm trying to bring this in at the end of the css reference so it prevents pulling the cached version.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/core.css?version=<%= noCache%>">
```

This would make the url "./css/core.css?version=<%= noCache%>" literal and not plug in the variable. After some reading I've found out that Inline Expressions aren't supported in .net. The weird thing is, before I figured that out I did this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/core.css?version=<%= noCache%>"  <%= noCache%> />
```

For whatever reason it works when I use this. Can someone explain to me why and how it'd be best to set something like this up without weird workaround.

AppSite.Master:

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AppSite.master.cs" Inherits="APP_Partnership.AppSite" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title><%# noCache%></title>

    <link runat="server" id="CSS1" rel="stylesheet" href="<%= noCache%>"/>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            APP SITE
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

AppSite.Master.cs:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace APP_Partnership
{
    public partial class AppSite : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {

        public string noCache = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: [Inline Expressions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976112/introduction-to-asp-net-inline-expressions-in-the-net-framework) *are* supported in ASP.NET WebForm however it should be place inside a aspx/ascx file in order to get evaluated and executed. Placing it into a CSS file won't make any effect.

Comment: @abatishchev this is in the AppSite.Master page. This isn't in the css file but instead referencing the css file with a variable tail string to prevent caching.

Comment: Please provide full code for your master page

Comment: @abatishchev I've updated with the Site.Master and the code behind

Comment: Remove the `runat="server"` if you do not need to access the link from code behind. If you do then use a [databinding expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46955762/want-to-use-databind-minqty-with-input-html-control-in-c-net).

Comment: @VDWWD I'm using a <%# noCache%> with a databind for the entire href in my codebehind now. I just wish modular inline insertion worked. Thanks!

Comment: Don't add say a versions number to try to prevent caching, write the entire line you'd use to import the external css file from the inline expression `<%=<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css?id=Date.now().ToString()">%>` etc.

Comment: @Sanguine this  is kind of what I did but instead just made the noCache data bound and set it to the entire computed href.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a UserControl to do that.
Here the code for the usercontrol ascx page:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CacheControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Usercontrols_CacheControl" %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/core.css?version=<%= noCache%>">
```

The code behind file:

```
protected string noCache = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Adding to the Masterpage:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="MyTagName" TagName="CacheControl" Src="~/Usercontrols/CacheControl.ascx" %>
```

and in the head section:

```
<MyTagName:CacheControl ID="CacheControl"  runat="server" />
```

The output on the page in the header looks like that:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/core.css?version=3">
```

Hope this helps.